# i want to set cell using string "," in python excel. but excel is terrible

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x, win32com

I want to set cell using string "," but it doesn't work.

This is my code.

```
import win32com.client

xlsfile = "D:\\Temp\\test.xlsx"
xl = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = xl.Workbooks.open(xlsfile)
sh = wb.Sheets[0]
sh.Cells(1,1).value = "20342,20343"
wb.Save()  
xl.Quit()
```

I expect the result `20342,20343(string)` but Excel gives the result `2,034,220,343(number)`. Maybe "," is the problem.

Excel auto number set is terrible!!!!

Comment: Have you tried a leading `'`, e.g. `"'20342,20343"` this informs excel to treat the rest as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a leading `'`, e.g. `"'20342,20343"` this informs excel to treat the rest as a string.